# Precipitation of a lead(II) sulfate

Tags: solubility, precipitation

> Lead (II) sulfate precipitate can be dissolved if:
>
> a) We add an acid
>
> b) We add EDTA
>
> c) None of the above is true.

I think EDTA is a ligand, and if you want to dissolve the sulfate, then Pb sticks with EDTA to form a complex. And so more Pb will be formed to balance the reaction.

Answer (score 1):

The stability constant of $\ce{Pb−EDTA}$ complex is $\ce{10^{18}}$, which is huge. The solubility product of $\ce{PbSO_4}$ is $10^{−8}$
, which cannot be compared to the effect of $\ce{EDTA}$. So the precipitate $\ce{PbSO4}$ must be soluble in $\ce{EDTA}$ solutions. These numerical data have been taken from J. G. Stark, Chemistry Data Book, John Murray, London, $1994$